# Firefox and other browsers not opennig, possibly relatd to NFS

Tags: nfs, firefox, browser

I have a setup with a NFS server sharing the /home directory with some clients. Randomly, those clients are not able to open any browser (firefox, chrome, vscode [which is browser based]). I have not been able to find the full cause. Normally a full restart of both server and clients fix things, the browsers open, but then the problem appears again.
The problem is present only in the clients. Firefox, for instance, just stops loading and does not opens. In contrast, for the same user, firefox opens in the server
After using strace, I can see that firefox stops on the client when it is processing some lock file, which comes from the nfs directory, as the next picture shows

[image]

(I had to use ctrl+z at the end to then kill the strace process)
The next one is the same section on the server (the /home dir is local)
[image]

I hope anyone can give me a hint on how to at least track or test the origin of the problem. I suspect it is NFS related due to the differences in client and server problems, and I have even tested nfs using nfstest, but currently I am clueless and cannot just restart the whole system since some users are running jobs and that is just a temporal solution. **I must note that other NFS related processes, like sharing the home (reading and writing files) work without noticeable problems.**

Following [Unable to open Firefox and some other applications after switching to new NIS and NFS servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/988061/unable-to-open-firefox-and-some-other-applications-after-switching-to-new-nis-an) , I also deactivated, activated and played with nfs ports but it did not work.

Thanks in advance

NOTE: Distribution Slackware 15.0 current

Answer (score 0):

For firefox you can try adding the preference `storage.nfs_filesystem` manually in `about:config`

`storage.nfs_filesystem: true`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when the problem appears again since I had to restart everything again and the problem vanished. But surely it will come out again, and then I will check this.